# Print console.log/alert on React Component

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to display data from an Event using Laravel into a React Component. While testing with `console.log` or `alert`, the message displays correctly as I wish. But being the noob that I'm, I don't know how to display the new event's data like I'm displaying the table's data using axios in the example bellow.

Like displaying the infos **IN** the component rather than externally using `alert` or `console.log`. Tried `return` and it didn't work.

**React component :**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
 
class Patient extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            patients : []
        };
    }

        componentDidMount() {
            axios.get('api/patients')
            .then(response => {this.setState({patients: response.data})})
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
            
           window.Echo.channel('home')
                .listen('NewPatient', (data)  => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data));
            }, (e) => {
                alert(data);})
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>

            <ul>
              { this.state.patients.map(patient => <li>{patient.nom}</li>)}
            </ul>

            </div>
          )
        }
      }

export default Patient;
```

I want to display the data of this event in an HTML list, so each time there is a new output the list updates itself.

```
        window.Echo.channel('home')
            .listen('NewPatient', (data)  => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, (e) => {
            alert(data);})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set state:

```
window.Echo.channel('home')
    .listen('NewPatient', newPatientData => {
        this.setState({
            patients: this.state.patients.concat(newPatientData)
        })
    }, e => {
        console.log("Error", e)
    })
```

Comment: I got it to work ! `patients: [data]` instead of `patients: data` . But there is a problem, each time an entry is added, the old one disappears and the new one appears, any idea ?

Comment: I update my answer, try that: ...
patients: this.state.patients.push(newPatientData) ...

Comment: I have the following error now `app.js:5241 Uncaught TypeError: this.state.patients.map is not a function`

Comment: My mistake, change push with concat

Comment: Yes it's working :D ! Thank you so much man. Little last question if it's possible, can I display the last elements from the top rather than the bottom ?

Comment: it's simple, add .slice(0).reverse() to array patients in your render:
 <ul>              { this.state.patients.slice(0).reverse().map(patient => <li>{patient.nom}</li>)}
            </ul>

Comment: Yes ! Thank you so so much man really appreciate your help. I'm still newbie as you can see, if you have any good website/pdf to learn about react I will be welcoming it. Anyway thank you again !